# How do I use Chrome's Developer Tools to catch the end destination for a click-event?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

As a policy for security I want to stay logged-in by default to my social media networks, but I do not want external desktop links to open in my browser that is logged in. So my default browser-mode is `--incognito`. I have an issue with [Chromium's Signal App crashing when my browser is set to default in incognito mode.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910533/chromium-signal-app-crashing-in-xubuntu) This much I've figured out.

I want to have a bookmark that I can manually run in my logged in browser to run the Signal app.

The Chrome web store [provides one such link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/signal-private-messenger/bikioccmkafdpakkkcpdbppfkghcmihk?hl=en). I can run signal by running Chromium outside of incognito mode and clicking in the webstore `LAUCNH APP`. I would like to use the Developer Tools to catch that even and know what the end-url is that triggers the Signal App.

How do I go about introspecting that?

Comment: There is no URL. Chrome apps are launched via [chrome.management.launchApp()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-launchApp) (it's whitelisted for the webstore) which you can use in your own extension that runs Signal. There are several/many existing extensions that provide similar functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand the specifics of your use case, but going off of the title of your question, perhaps this will help:

1. Set an [event listener breakpoint](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#event-listeners) for **Mouse** > `click`.
2. Click on the element to trigger the listener(s).
3. [Step through the code](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#stepping).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for here. However, I still wasn't able to answer my own question even knowing how to do this, so I asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43857228/124486