# What is the method the Chrome Web Store uses to launch an application?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, chrome-web-store

I'm just wondering how the Chrome Web Store is implemented. There is a web site that has an option to `LAUNCH APP`. What happens when that button is clicked. How does it go about launching the extension?

You can find the [Chrome Signal Application here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/signal-private-messenger/bikioccmkafdpakkkcpdbppfkghcmihk?hl=en)

Comment: Probably https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-launchApp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome uses an internal extension to grant special permissions to that page (namely "webstorePrivate" and "management"). There's not much to it in Chrome proper:

- The manifest for webstore_app is at https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/resources/webstore_app/manifest.json
- The management API is documented at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management, since it's usable by other extensions
- The webstorePrivate API is not documented except at https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/api/webstore_private.json, since it's not usable by other extensions.

All the code that actually calls these APIs is served from Google's servers for the web store page itself. As a starting point, if you open the developer tools on the Chrome web store and type `chrome.runtime.id`, it will respond with `"ahfgeienlihckogmohjhadlkjgocpleb"`.